# How to instruct PySide2 application to use qt5ct settings?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm experimenting with very simple PySide2 tutorial examples and noticed that the style and font size are very different from the style of "normal" Qt applications.

I'm using qt5ct in Linux Mint 18 but PySide2 app ignores the settings:

[image]

The application is very simple:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, Qt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    file = QFile("mainwindow.ui")
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    loader = QUiLoader()
    window = loader.load(file)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there any way of instructing it to use qt5ct settings? Google gives nothing useful so any hints are appreciated!

Comment: I'm also getting this warning when running an application:
`Please set Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute`
I'm not sure if it is related with inability to get the correct style.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a solution to this problem, but I have a potential hint towards finding a solution. On the Plasma desktop, pip installed versions of PyQt5 and PySide2 use the system style, font, and icons. Therefore, there must be something that Plasma does to get them to respect the system settings. The issue is that when trying to find information about what that could be all you can find is the QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = "qt5ct" or QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = "kde" advice that does not work for non package manager installed versions of PyQt5 and PySide2.

Answer (score 3):

Found myself here a few times and eventually found my own solution.

See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-842

This issue seems to occur when your pyside2 was installed via pip but your Qt was installed by the system (Manjaro/Arch in my case).

This is what I got when using the pip version of pyside2:

```
>>> from PySide2.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory
>>> print(QStyleFactory.keys())

[u'Windows', u'Fusion']
```

When using the pyside2 packaged by arch linux I get:

```
>>> from PySide2.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory
>>> print(QStyleFactory.keys())

['Adwaita-Dark', 'Adwaita', 'Breeze', 'bb10dark', 'bb10bright', 'kvantum-dark', 'kvantum', 'cleanlooks', 'gtk2', 'cde', 'motif', 'plastique', 'qt5ct-style', 'Oxygen', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
```

Using the pyside2 package that came with my system instead (sudo pacman -S pyside2) solved this for me. My pyside2 app now uses the system Qt theme.

Comment: Well, there are two problems. First, in Debian-based distros (Ubuntu, Mint) pyside2 is not packaged so it could only be installed from pip. Second, I still can't see any logic: there is just one set of Qt libs in the system, so why source of pyside2 installation  should matter?

Comment: The source of the pyside2 implementation matters because of the Qt libs it was linked against when it was built, and any flags that were set at that time. It doesn't look like pyside2 will use your system Qt libs if it was installed via pip (the pip install seems to include pre-build qt dependencies, which means it will not use your system ones). There's some documentation at https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/ for building pyside2 from source, which may help

Answer (score 1):

In order for all your applications to use qt5ct you must establish `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = "qt5ct"` as a variable of your session or system, for example in the `~/.xprofile`:

```
[ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "KDE" ] || [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "GNOME" ] || export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
```

If you only want to be established in only your application, you must pass it through the command line:

```
python /path/of/your/script.py --platformtheme qt5ct
```

Or better add it by code:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.argv.extend(["--platformtheme", "qt5ct"]) 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    file = QtCore.QFile("mainwindow.ui")
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
    loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
    window = loader.load(file)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This has no effect at all. Adding this flag changes nothing. 
I have `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"` in my .profile and all other qt5 apps on my machine are behaving correctly and are using qt5ct theme.

Comment: how strange, that flag that I use in archlinux.

Comment: @yesint Have you used the last method: `sys.argv.extend(["--platformtheme", "qt5ct"])` ?

Comment: Yes. It does not work.
The flag itself works - all other apps are using it happily, but not PySide apps. I have no idea what's wrong.